# slave mode mplayer pipe

Tags: debian, fifo, mplayer

I am loading mplayer in slave mode like this:

```
mplayer -slave -idle -input file=/tmp/pipe
```

the pipe file contains:

```
loadfile /mymusic/1.mp3
```

Sofar it's running my 1.mp3 as expected.
But i want to append seek and pause into the pipe but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong or is it even possible like this?

I have tried the following in another terminal without luck:

```
echo pause > /tmp/pipe
echo pause >> /tmp/pipe
printf "pause\n" > /tmp/pipe
printf "pause\n" >> /tmp/pipe
```

It looks like it only opens the STDIN on startup of mplayer -slave. the OS is debian 8.4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make the FIFO file pipe with the command

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
```

instead of just writing into the file.

Comment: Thank you. The best easy solution I found.